# Remove preveous appended list items before clicking tthe button

Tags: javascript

I'm using Wikipedia API for my project. When i click a button to show a quote my code dynamically appends articles from wikipedia to ul related to the particular author. However when i click the button new li of others authors added to ul, so old articles (li) not removed. I have tried to put code in for loop before append to ul but then when i click the button it adds only one article, instead of all.

My code is:

```
var getWikiAuthorBio = function(author) {
  var url =  'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + author + '&format=json&callback=wikiCalback'

//////////////
//Wiki request
/////////////
var wikirequest = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url:url,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(wikiData) {

      // Fetch the biographical information
      var bioName = wikiData[2][0];

      // Check if instead of bio there is a phrase "The article may refer to...." if so then change indices
      if (bioName.indexOf('may refer to') >= 0) {
        bioName = wikiData[2][1];
      } else {
        var bioName = wikiData[2][0];
      }

      var wikiArcticles = wikiData[1];
      var wikiArticlesShortInfo = wikiData[2]
      console.log(wikiArticlesShortInfo);

      for (var i=0; i < wikiArcticles.length; i++) {

        console.log("Each article " + wikiArcticles[i]);
        domCache.$wikiArticlesList.append('<li class="articleItem">'+ wikiArcticles[i]+ '</li>');   
      }

      // Short biography
      console.log(bioName);
      console.log(wikiArcticles);
      console.log(url);

      domCache.$bioDiv.text(bioName);



      } // end of success
    });
}// wikirequest

wikirequest();

}
```

[Link to Codepen](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/YWjALR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the jQuery [empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) function.

`domCache.$wikiArticlesList.empty();`

Put in before the for-loop

Answer (score 1):

Empty your list before your loop.

```js
var getWikiAuthorBio = function(author) {
  var url =  'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + author + '&format=json&callback=wikiCalback'

//////////////
//Wiki request
/////////////
var wikirequest = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url:url,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(wikiData) {

      // Fetch the biographical information
      var bioName = wikiData[2][0];

      // Check if instead of bio there is a phrase "The article may refer to...." if so then change indices
      if (bioName.indexOf('may refer to') >= 0) {
        bioName = wikiData[2][1];
      } else {
        var bioName = wikiData[2][0];
      }

      var wikiArcticles = wikiData[1];
      var wikiArticlesShortInfo = wikiData[2]
      console.log(wikiArticlesShortInfo);

      domCache.$wikiArticlesList.html(''); // <--- add this
      for (var i=0; i < wikiArcticles.length; i++) {

        console.log("Each article " + wikiArcticles[i]);
        domCache.$wikiArticlesList.append('<li class="articleItem">'+ wikiArcticles[i]+ '</li>');   
      }

      // Short biography
      console.log(bioName);
      console.log(wikiArcticles);
      console.log(url);

      domCache.$bioDiv.text(bioName);



      } // end of success
    });
}// wikirequest

wikirequest();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

please try .html instead of .append:

```
domCache.$wikiArticlesList.html('<li class="articleItem">'+ wikiArcticles[i]+ '</li>')
```

or just remove the last one before you append new one:

```
domCache.$wikiArticlesList.children('li:last').remove();
domCache.$wikiArticlesList.append('<li class="articleItem">'+ wikiArcticles[i]+ '</li>')
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, html method clear  dom but append only first article. I have already found an answer! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.append()` or `.html()`.

```
// with .append()
domCache.$wikiArticlesList.empty();  
for (var i=0; i < wikiArcticles.length; i++) {

  console.log("Each article " + wikiArcticles[i]);   
  domCache.$wikiArticlesList.append('<li class="articleItem">'+ wikiArcticles[i]+ '</li>');   
}

// with .html()
var wikiArticlesListHtml = '';
for (var i=0; i < wikiArcticles.length; i++) {

  console.log("Each article " + wikiArcticles[i]);   
  html += '<li class="articleItem">'+ wikiArcticles[i]+ '</li>\n';   
}
domCache.$wikiArticlesList.html(wikiArticlesListHtml);
```

Note: `.append()` works with more than just strings containing HTML, whereas `.html()` only works with strings containing HTML.